# Error Backup odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

Any help please I'am beginner in odoo

I do this code for backup (odoo10)

```py
class db_backup_manual(models.Model):
_name = "db.backup.manual.ept"
db_id = fields.Many2one('db.autobackup.ept', required=True, domain=[('active','=','True')], help="Select a database for which you want to generate manual backup.")


def data_save(self, context=None):
    data =  self.read(self)
    #print str(data[0]['db_id'])   
    confs = self.pool.get('db.autobackup.ept').browse(self,[data[0]['db_id'][0]])
   for rec in confs:
        db_list = self.pool.get('db.autobackup.ept').get_db_list(self, [], rec.host, rec.port)
        if rec.name in db_list:
            try:
                if not os.path.isdir(rec.backup_dir):
                    os.makedirs(rec.backup_dir)
            except:
                raise
            result = self.pool.get('db.autobackup.ept').ept_backup(self,[rec.id], rec.name, rec.backup_dir,False,rec.ftp_enable,rec.FTP_id,rec,rec.keep_backup_local)
    return {'type': 'ir.actions.act_window_close'}   

db_backup_manual()
```

in line :
 `confs = self.pool.get('db.autobackup.ept').browse(self,[data[0]['db_id'][0]])`

I have this error :

`Exception during JSON request handling
KeyError: 'db_id'`

Comment: The `KeyError` means, you trying to access a `key` which doesn't exist.

You trying to get value from a dictionary using a key `db_id` which is does't exist in dictionary `data[0]`.
Just print the variable `data` and check if `db_id` exist or not.

Comment: Free module available for auto backup in odoo apps check this : https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/10.0/auto_backup/

Comment: @Heroic in this module dependacy PYSFTP does'nt install I try with sudo pip install pysftp but always stays
 Import Error

Comment: @ KbiR data return nothing

Comment: Try this code `confs = self.env['db.autobackup.ept'].browse([self.db_id.id])`